# SQL to find number of expired products and total number of products by category

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue with an SQL query.

This is my product table :

product 
• id
• name
• price
• expired
• fk_category

And I want number of products expired and total number of products group by category.

I write the following query and I have difficulties to finish it :

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as nb_expired, COUNT (id) as nb_product
FROM product
WHERE expired = 1
GROUP BY fk_category;
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement in the `count` to only those expired:

```
SELECT sum(case when expired = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as nb_expired
,      COUNT (id) as nb_product
FROM   product
GROUP
BY     fk_category
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fk_category, sum(case when expired = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as expired_count,
COUNT (1) as total 
FROM   product 
GROUP BY     fk_category
```